# printing pyramid pattern with asterisks

Tags: java

I need to write a code for pyramid pattern with asterisks. yeah, it sounds like the codes on everywhere. but, i need to make a pyramid with a number of asterisks, not a number of rows.

for example, if user gave 9, then need to print a pyramid until the asterisks runs out. It should be center pyramids.

I've tried with the number of rows. but i have no idea how to print with the number of asterisks. while loop could be my answer, but i'm not sure..

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 5; // number of rows

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = n - i; j > 1; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

the result should be like this, but without space between asterisks..

```
    *   
   * *  
  * * * 
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

my output is showing exactly same thing, but i'm using a number of rows, not number of asterisks.

Comment: What should the last row look like, if there aren't enough asterisks left for a full row?

Comment: What about simply having a counter of number-of-stars-printed, and exit the loop when that reaches the desired number? You either need to calculate how many rows are needed or just start to print "a lot" of rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java algorithm to make a straight pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191381/java-algorithm-to-make-a-straight-pyramid) and a more direct duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057062/print-pyramid-pattern-in-java

Comment: @TheScientificMethod In case of `a=7` , number of rows `n=(int)Math.sqrt(7)=2`, so `n+1` is `3`. There should not be 4 rows in this case?

Comment: The formula you want is actually (sqrt(8*n+1)-1)/2

Comment: Did you even look at the second link?

Comment: Remember that your professor is likely to ask you where that formula came from, and might not accept "some random guy on the Internet" as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal solution, but you set a maximum number of rows with `n=100`.

Then you define your `asterix` number to break out of nested loop. `ctr` is the total number of asterix.

It goes until desired number `asterix` reached, checking `ctr` value.

```
int n = 100;
int ctr = 0;
int asterix = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = n - i; j > 1; j--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        ctr++;
        System.out.print("* ");
        if(ctr == asterix ){
            i=j=n;
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Based on @Hans Keﬆing's idea.

Comment: What if I set incorrect asterisk amount, e.g. 17?

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 5; // number of asterisks
    int max = (int)((1+Math.sqrt(1+8*n))/2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = max - i; j > 1; j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
            --n;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```